# Split Array Function on Email PlainBody() MSG using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the following code below to grab emails, get the plainbody(), date and messageto bring them into Google sheet in COLUMN A. 
Then in the spreadsheet I copy down the formula in COLUMN C

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A3,"|")))
```

(Which I tested this works as well - not sure if one is preferred)

```
=SPLIT($A2,"|")
```

I'd like to combine these functions and have attempted the following

```
function getEmails() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var threads = GmailApp.search("is:starred in:TanWebOppCRM");

    for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
            var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
            var dat = messages[j].getDate();

            var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A2,"|")';
            /*var msgParse = '=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT($A2,"|")))';*/
            ss.appendRow([msg, dat, msgParse]);
        }
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
    }
}
```

This DOES "WORK". For example - I know I just sent myself a test email that can be extracted. I know the next row that WILL be appended is Row 30 - and change the code

```
 var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A2,"|")';
```

to

```
 var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A30,"|")';
```

Then the extraction works, and you see the split happen.
If I was to import 2 new rows - obviously

```
$A30 /* stays A30 - so I tried-
var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A[j],"|")';
```

Just to see if the `[j]` dynamically changed - even though I know `j` is for message loop

## The question...

- **how do I get the following line to increment to the append row value**
  so that each loop changes the row reference to the appended row - so if I was starting from row 30

  ```
  var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A30,"|")';
  var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A31,"|")';
  var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A32,"|")';
  ```

Is what the incremental msgParse value data would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the formula via string concatenation.
If you always just append you can just get the last row and add 1 (because the new row will be one row below) and use that as the row reference:

```
var msgParse = '=SPLIT($A' + (ss.getLastRow() + 1) + ', "|")';
```

Comment: I tried a dozen different ways including something close to this - but never got it exact. Question though - I'm about to try this - should their be more " quotes or is one missing in the beginning?

Comment: sorry, i messed up single and double quotes, please check the updated answer

Comment: I started with the " at the beginning then realized the above and came up with the same thing. But however - it's not parsing any longer. In the Editor - I noticed "sheet" is not blue. Looking at my original script  - it's not declared below. But the last few things I had done either errorred or did not process. Do you have any ideas? I'm accepting your answer on split array as soon as I confirm it worked.

Comment: I accepted this answer because my question was about the array split. Moving the suggested answer OUT OF the first FOR loop -and run a log on it - it outputs what I expect. For some reason it just doesn't execute in the for loop so I'll open a different question. Thanks @Robin

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new to Script - and I couldn't find this answer - I wanted to add my own answer.

@Robin definitely pointed me in the right direction - I didn't realize I can use string concatenation - however the solution provided did not increment and once that string concatenation was written - it remain for the rest of the FOR loop

The final piece was adding a counter - I could probably eliminate the first row = variable and there is probably a way to make this more efficient But it took in 20 sample emails from gmail and parsed them into spreadsheet in maybe 6 or 7 seconds.

```
function getEmails() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var threads = GmailApp.search("is:starred in:TannerWebOppCRM");
    var row = ss.getLastRow();   

    for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        var newrow = row + 1;

        for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
            var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
            var dat = messages[j].getDate();
            var msgParse ='=SPLIT($A'+ (newrow) + ', "|")';
            ss.appendRow([msg, dat, msgParse]);
            newrow = newrow + 1;
        }
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
    }
}
```

To complete this post I wanted to include the update and addition to the answer I accepted because that technically answered my question - just didn't put it into context how to make it work in my script.

Comment: Glad you could get it to work. Try providing sample data next time, that way whoever answers also has the chance to validate the correctness of their answer.

Comment: @robin - I would have had I had a problem with the split but in my original question I had confirmed the split worked 2 or 3 different ways. I also posted that your suggestion did the split. This was in **no** way about validating the data -  besides data sample would have been as easy as some|data|here just by looking at the split. Why I posted the answer was that your answer was incomplete - as the contents of the script and the fact it needed to increment was visible in the initial script. Every other variable was incremental in that FOR loop except your answer.